# Gnuplot horizontal bars on every tic

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, how can i draw horizontal bars across the entire graph at every tic mark on the y axis? Just as a sort of visual indicator of where a specific point is.

(apologies if this is simple, but googling was fruitless)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the `set grid` command.  For example:

```
set grid ytics
```

will show horizontal bars across the graph at every y tic.  `set grid` by itself will do horizontal and vertical bars.